# Всплывающий VIEW

Tags: android, view

Возможно кто-то встречался, давно хотелось узнать как делать "всплывающие" окна в андроиде, как я понимаю такое представление появлется поверх основного лейаута,  но имеет координаты на экране в зависимости от вызывающего его элемента.

Пример:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Для того , чтобы вывести всплывающее меню ,необходимо использовать класс `PopupMenu`
Простой пример:

```
public class PopupExample extends Activity {      
 Button button;
 PopupMenu popupMenu;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, button);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_1:
                    // действие по нажатию на пункт 1
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_2:
                    // действие по нажатию на пункт 2
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_3:
                    // действие по нажатию на пункт 3
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

res/menu/popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_1" android:title="Menu 1" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_2" android:title="Menu 2"/>
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_3" android:title="Menu 3"/>
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет! Попробуйте найти ответ на свой вопрос [здесь](http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-xml-drawables.html).

Comment: Нет. Это не то

Answer (score 0):

Если еще интересно, то это можно сделать с помощью [PopupWindow](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-create-popup-window-in-android.html)